# Need help getting CLisp to read standard input into a list

Tags: python, lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I'm working on converting some existing Python code to CLisp just as an exercise ...

The program reads a list of numbers and creates mean, min, max and standard deviation from the list. I have the file-based function working:

```
(defun get-file (filename)
   (with-open-file (stream filename)
     (loop for line = (read-line stream nil)
      while line
      collect (parse-float line))))
```

This works when I call it as

```
(get-file "/tmp/my.filename")
```

... but I want the program to read standard input and I've tried
various things with no luck.

Any advice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just separate concerns:

```
(defun get-stream (stream)
  (loop for line = (read-line stream nil)
        while line
        collect (parse-float line)))

(defun get-file (filename)
  (with-open-file (stream filename)
    (get-stream stream)))
```

Then you can use `get-file` like you already do, and `(get-stream *standard-input*)`.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `*standard-input*` is bound to standard input:

```
(defun get-from-standard-input ()
   (loop for line = (read-line *standard-input* nil)
         while line
         collect (parse-float line)))
```